# Getting value from dymanic text variable into Contact Form 7

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I have an inscription form and I'm using Contact Form 7, [Conditional Fields plugin](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) and [Dynamic Text Extension](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/).
I want to show different prices according to the option selected and get the price for showing on the email confirmation (and save into database with [Contact Form DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/)).

With the following code the price is displayed correctly on the web, but always appears with the same value in the confirmation email

```
Service type [select* serv_type "Regular" "Exceptional"]
[group g_regular clear_on_hide]
  Price [dynamictext amount readonly "65"]
  [dynamichidden price_value "65"]
[/group]
[group g_exceptional clear_on_hide]
  Price [dynamictext amount readonly "45"]
  [dynamichidden price_value "45"]
[/group]
```

The conditional code is

```
show [g_regular] if [serv_type] equals "Regular"
show [g_exceptional] if [serv_type] equals "Exceptional"
```

And the email template code is

```
Subject: Inscription registered ([serv_type])    
New [serv_type] inscription with [price_value]€ ([amount]).
```

The **price** and **amount** value is always **65** on the email confirmation and should be **45** if is selected **Exceptional**

Comment: Hi crossmax, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as Contact Form 7) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt for the notice! I don't knew about it and I thought it was similar to stackoverflow

Comment: There is some overlap with SO and this point of view is sometimes debated in meta. I just thought you should get a heads up. There is a chance someone who knows about this area might offer an answer anyway. It's odd like that here.